# Angular JS trying add a text to speech function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

```html
<ion-view view-title="Call Center" >
<ion-content = "padding">

<div ng-controller="CallCtrl1" class ="callPosition">
<!--button >Broken Lamp</button-->


<p class = "callMessage">  {{jalantol}}  </p>
<a href="tel:{{telpon}}" ng-click = "panggil()" class= "button button-positive callButton" >

  <p class = "callText"> Call </p>

</a>

</div>
<script>
     function play(){
            var text = "Keos bat skjadnsakjdnkasjndkjsand"
            var url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&tl=id&q='+text;
            var a = new Audio(url);
                window.a.play();
            }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="play();"> Speak it </button>
    </body>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I'm newbie in ionic and web programming.
I have an ionic project using angular js, when I'm try to add text to speech function, it give an error "ReferenceError: play is not defined[Learn More]". 
Anyone have any suggestion? 
Thank's before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use speechSynthesis,

```
 var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("this is a test");
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

[`Working Demo`](https://plnkr.co/edit/M644SS0Qq1wDMhUm8Mhc?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I know the problem is in controller.js, I must make the play() function at controller and make like this: $scope.play = function(). The problem solved now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a.play();
```

instead of

```
window.a.play();
```